# Change authentication Timeout value programmatically C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my web config file

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/signin.aspx" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

I tried following way

```
   Configuration conn = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
            AuthenticationSection section = (AuthenticationSection)conn.SectionGroups.Get("system.web").Sections.Get("authentication");
            FormsAuthenticationConfiguration currentForms = section.Forms;
            var tim = currentForms.Timeout;
            currentForms.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
            int timeout = currentForms.Timeout.Minutes;
```

But it doesn't change in web config file.
Can you please help me to Change authentication Timeout value in C# code.

Comment: What is the timeout you currently have?  There is sometimes a 30 second delay waiting for a proxy to timeout when there is not proxy.  So setting the proxy to null will eliminate the 30 second delay.

Comment: @jdweng Current time out is 1 min, but i need to change it into some other value.

Comment: Which framework, and why not just change the web.config itself? Changing the value from C# code seems to invalidate the reason for using a web.config file.

Comment: You are altering it in memory, but you are not saving it. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.save?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks guys .i have fix this issue by modifying Authentication ticket cookie value .
We can save the configuration by calling Configuration.Save() method.But This will restart the application pool and kick out all users from the application.